# Is AWS Lambda the proper way of running a batch job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, batch-processing

I have a batch job that I need to run on AWS. I'm wondering what's the best service to use. The job needs to run once a day, so I think that naturally AWS Lambda with a CloudWatch Rule triggering it would do it. However, I'm starting to think that AWS Lambda is thought to be used as a service to handle requests. [This AWS official library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot) to integrate Spring-Boot is very oriented to handle HTTP requests, and when creating a lambda via AWS Console, only test cases that send an input to the lambda can be written.

Then, is this a use case for AWS Lambda? Also, these functions can run up to 15 minutes. What should I use if my job needs to run longer?

Answer (score 21):

The purpose of Lambda, as compared to AWS EC2, is to simplify building smaller, on-demand applications that are responsive to events and new information.

If your batch is running within a limit of 15 minutes then you can go with a lambda function.

But if you want batch processing to be done, you should check [AWS batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/).

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-batch-run-batch-computing-jobs-on-aws/) is nice article which demonstrates the usage of AWS batch.

---

If you are already using some batch framework like `spring-batch`, you can also take a look at `ECS` scheduled task with `Fargate`.

With `ECS Fargate` you can launch and stop container services that you need to run only at certain times.
Here are some related articles on [Fargate event and scheduled task](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/aws-fargate-now-supports-time-and-event-based-task-scheduling/) and [Scheduled Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html).

Comment: oh, didn't know about aws batch. This might be a better implementation for ours too! awesome

Comment: @groobienewbie thanks. yes..previously we have also used ECS scheduled tasks for batch processing, but aws batch is more dedicated and easy to use.

Comment: Some additional considerations: Lambda has some hard limits (1K max concurrent instances, 10 GB memory limit, 15 minute runtime limit).  Batch assists in overcoming these limits.

Answer (score 3):

If you're confident that your function will only run at maximum of 15mins, AWS Lambda **could be** the solution. Here are the [AWS Lambda limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) that could help you decide on that.

Also note that lambda has cold start, it's when it will run slower at first but will eventually pick up the pace. Here are some good reads about it that could help you decide on the lambda direction, but feel free to check on any articles that could better explain at your disposal.

- [This one](https://hackernoon.com/cold-starts-in-aws-lambda-f9e3432adbf0) shows a brief lists that you would like to consider and the factors affecting it.
- [This one](https://hackernoon.com/im-afraid-you-re-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong-7d907f278a4f) might have a deeper explanation of the cold start with regards to how it works internally.

> What should I use if my job needs to run longer?

Depending on your infrastructure, you could maybe explore [Scheduled Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html)

Comment: As of 2021/22, I think the issues of cold start are over, right?

Comment: @ankush981 There is is still a cold start phase of AWS Lambda due to it's nature I think, but it has been improved ever since. You can also further improve your lambda execution time by making your lambda function lightweight. You can see the networking improvement documentation in AWS [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/).